# Show recently changed or uploaded documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I know there has been previous questions on the subject, but I haven't yet found an answer suited to my situation.

I would like to create a list/app/webpart on my SharePoint page to display any recently changed or uploaded documents in any of my document libraries. By searching I found that I can achieve this either by the context search webpart, data view webpart or content query webpart. Or maybe some entire different method?

Any thoughts on which method would be most suited for SharePoint Online 2013, no-code or by code?

Comment: Use content by search web part and filter on documents content type and sort by date modified (desc).

Comment: Okay thank you. Should i activate any features for the cswp to work? When i edit the query i see results in the "search result prewiev" window, but nothing appears when i press ok and stops editing the site?

Comment: If you could see CSWP, all the required features should be already active. Check your CSWP properties and display templates (control and item). More info: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html

Comment: One of the easiest methods is using a Content Query Web Part (CQWP). You can configure it right from the GUI ToolBox/Configuration window. If you want an example, you can create a sub-site with the Document Center site template and there you have one CQWP working as an example. Only thing you need to change in the web part configuration box is that it will include all libraries in specified site url instead of the one library. :)

Comment: Did you try to add the web part "Highlighted Content"?